# Is there a way of resizing a Label depending on the size of its text?

Tags: java, javafx

So I've got a `ConfirmationBox` whose purpose is to display a question and allow the user to either accept or decline.

```
public class ConfirmationBox
{
    private Stage primary_stage ;
    private boolean btnYesClicked ;

    // 4 parameters : the label to be displayed, the title of the ConfirmationBox, the text for the yes_btn and the text for the no_btn
    public boolean show(String message, String title, String textYes, String textNo)
    {
        btnYesClicked = false ;

        primary_stage = new Stage() ;
        primary_stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL) ;
        primary_stage.setTitle(title) ;
        primary_stage.setMinWidth(250) ;
        primary_stage.setResizable(false) ;

        Label lbl = new Label() ;
        lbl.setText(message) ;

        Button yes_btn = new Button() ;
        yes_btn.setText(textYes) ;
        yes_btn.setPrefWidth(50) ;
        yes_btn.setPrefHeight(20) ;
        yes_btn.setOnAction(e ->
        {
            btnYesClicked = true ;      // the yes_btn has been clicked
            primary_stage.close() ;
        }) ;

        Button no_btn = new Button() ;
        no_btn.setText(textNo) ;
        no_btn.setPrefWidth(50) ;
        no_btn.setPrefHeight(20) ;
        no_btn.setOnAction(e ->
        {
            btnYesClicked = false ;
            primary_stage.close() ;
        }) ;

        HBox paneBtn = new HBox(20) ;
        paneBtn.getChildren().addAll(yes_btn, no_btn) ;
        paneBtn.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER) ;

        VBox vbox = new VBox(20) ;
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(lbl, paneBtn) ;
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER) ;
        vbox.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE) ;

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 300, 150) ;
        primary_stage.setScene(scene) ;
        primary_stage.showAndWait() ;
        primary_stage.sizeToScene() ;

        return btnYesClicked ;      // return the value of btnYesClicked to notify what the user has selected
    }
}
```

When I pass in a string that's not very long(eg: "Log out of account?") as the text to be displayed, the entire text is shown in the window. However, if I were to pass in a long text the label does not automatically resize to fit the entire the text in as I expected. Can I please know how this can be achieved?

Comment: specifically: understand that you should not use hard-coded sizes/sizing hints for nodes

Comment: Curious...what's wrong with just using an Alert Dialog for something like this?

Comment: I haven't worked with an Alert Dialog before. 
I just looked it up. Guess that'll be a better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the following after the line containing "`Label lbl = new Label();`":

```
lbl.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

This will make the min width track the preferred width automatically.

It is also documented here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#USE_PREF_SIZE

Comment: yeah, that helps occasionally - but not here :) The overall sizing is constrained by the scene's size: to see, add the line to the code above and see how the label is still cut off, but now on both sides (that is, it is centered due to its layout in its parent which then is centered)

Comment: @kleopatra yeah, it worked as you said - the label is cut off on both sides. And then I did as you said above, I didn't explicitly specify the sizes for the nodes(specifically the Scene and stage). So this way the parent node grows to fit the size of the child node?